# Know how many table is modified on particular date in database in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-manager

I have a database with 40 tables in it. So I want to find tables which are modified on the particular date like

- How many tables were modified on `20 Aug 2011` in my database?

**UPDATE**
please note that I need the table name and not the record id

like the names of the table whose content were modified on  `20 Aug 2011`

Comment: Do you mean modified in terms of the *structure* of the table, or do you mean modified in terms of the *contents*?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever In terms of the contents...

Comment: You should then change the question you are asking. Is not `How many tables were modified` but `I want the name of every modified table on a particular day`

Comment: There's nothing built into SQL Server that records data changes in the way that you're after - you'd have to add something (triggers, maybe) but that would only work from now onwards.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**
@Damien_The_Unbeliever has a good point on his comment. My answer is only related to table structure, not inside data. In case you want to verify when data was changed then you need to add an `updated_date` column so you can query it and find when was modified.

Use catalog views, in particular `sys.tables`

```
DECLARE @auxDate datetime = '20120820 00:00:00'
SELECT tbl.name
  FROM sys.tables tbl
 WHERE modify_date = @auxDate
```

Modified to show table names. I had `WHERE modify_date >= @auxDate` but you want table names modified on a particular day, so updated the `WHERE` clause to show one day

Comment: This will give you all the tables modified after specific date.And not for particular date.

Comment: AFAIK, sys.tables is updated whenever, table column is added or changed. Are you sure it is updated when table data is changed?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever asked already about it. I answered thinking on table structure.

Answer (score -1):

IN case of data modification,

```
Alter table tablename add datemodified timestamp

select count(*) from tablename where datemodified = @yourdate
```